# Compact images of nowhere dense closed convex sets in a Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Let $B=-B$ be a nowhere dense bounded closed convex set in the Hilbert space $\ell_2$ such that the linear hull of $B$ is dense in $\ell_2$.

> **Question.** Is there a non-compact linear bounded operator $T:\ell_2\to \ell_2$ such that $T(B)$ is compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your revised assumption is that the norm (rather than semi-norm after the revision) on $\ell_2$ given by sup-ing against vectors in $B$ is not equivalent to the usual norm on any finite codimensional subspace.  So there is an ON sequence $x_n$ in $\ell_2$ s.t. $\sup \{\langle x_n,b\rangle : b\in B \} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Take for $T$ the orthogonal projection onto the closed span of the $x_n$.

Answer (score 3):

No, take $B$ to be the set of vectors in the unit ball of $l^2$ whose first coordinate is zero. If $T: l^2 \to l^2$ is a bounded operator and $T(B)$ is compact, then letting $C$ be the set of vectors in the unit ball which are nonzero only in the first coordinate (plus the zero vector), we have that $C$ is compact and therefore $T(C)$ is also compact. Thus $T(B+C) = T(B) + T(C)$ is compact, and $B + C$ contains the unit ball, so $T$ is a compact operator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is a trivial case (finite codimension). Let me add one more condition to exclude this case.

Comment: ... but if $B$ has infinite codimension then there will be a bounded noncompact operator which vanishes on $B$.

Comment: I had in mind infinite codimension in the sense that the linear hull is a dense subspace of the first Baire category and hence of infinite codimension in the algebraic sense. This was the true setting. For my purposes it suffices to assume that $B$ is the image of the unit ball of the Hilbert space under a non-open bounded operator $\ell_2\to\ell_2$.